# jQuery Append Not Appending Any Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am using Jquery to append data to a div. However, nothing shows up on the page after the append statement.

I tried using $(window).load to make sure the page is loaded but this still won't work.

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="clubcontent" data-inset="true">

</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page-tasklist', function () {
    $('clubcontent').listview();
    getClubs();
});

function getClubs() {

    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("clubs"));
    var clubcontent = $('clubcontent');

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        clubcontent.append('<li><a href="#" data-club-id=\"' + json[i].id + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>');
        alert(json[i].name);
    }

    clubcontent.listview( "refresh" );

};
```

Comment: no, when i alert values as i did in the for loop, it comes out perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of hashes missing in your javascript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page-tasklist', function () {
    $('#clubcontent').listview();
    getClubs();
});

function getClubs() {

    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("clubs"));
    var clubcontent = $('#clubcontent');

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        clubcontent.append('<li><a href="#" data-club-id=\"' + json[i].id + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>');
        alert(json[i].name);
    }

    clubcontent.listview( "refresh" );

};
```

And the (extended) html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="clubcontent" data-inset="true">
    <li> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
    <li> c </li>
    <li> d </li>
    <li> e </li>
</ul>
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LvUt9/

Comment: @user3630775 - check out this updated fiddle with sample data: http://jsfiddle.net/LvUt9/3/. 'captain theo' is correct, it was just a typo made a few times while selecting the element with the id `clubcontent`.

Comment: this looks the same as my code though? What's the difference, what did you change

Comment: @user3630775 - as 'captain theo' pointed out, you had `$('clubcontent')` instead of `$('#clubcontent')` twice in your code. This meant that you were actually looking for an element with that tag name e.g. `<clubcontent>` instead of one with that `id`.

Comment: Well, I keep on missing hashes and dots all the time... Glad to know I'm not the only one!!! I think a great help to that as well as many more issues is the "inspect element -> console" feature of google chrome...

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
$('<li><a href="#" data-club-id=\"' + json[i].id + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>').appendTo($('clubcontent'));
```

if it doesn't work probably a Json error so check the data with your network listener

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
$('<li><a href="#" data-club-id=\"' + json[i].id + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>').appendTo($('clubcontent'));
```

if it doesn't work probably a Json error so check the data with your network listener

and you a have a " ; " that is too much a the end